# Error when using lodash in InertiaJS + Vue inside event handler

Tags: laravel, vue.js, lodash, inertiajs

I have a `Vue + inertiajs` (`Laravel`) project in which I want to use the `._pull` function of `lodash` inside one of my Vue single file components.

Default configuration in `bootstrap.js`:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
window._ = _;
...
```

And in `app.js`:

```
import './bootstrap';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
...
```

**It works** when I call `_.pull` directly inside `<script setup>`.

However, when I use it in an event handler, e.g. inside a normal button:

```
<button @click="_.pull(array, 'a', 'c')">My button</button>
```

Then, console logs the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _ctx._.pull is not a function
at onClick (MyComponent.vue:243:114)
...
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is probably because the Vue component itself does not have access to the imported `_` alias.

Comment: What is your vue.js version?

Comment: Then, @Terry, any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: @bariskau last one, `Vue 3.2.45`

Comment: @andcl you can use the provide/inject option for vue3. Remember that you render the template on the backend, so no window object is created.

Comment: How about just calling a function on the `click` event? Then, in that function, you can call `_.pull()` without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need add it in mixin. try this way.

```
import _ from 'lodash';
window._ = _;

createApp({render: () => h(app, props)})
    .use(plugin)
    .mixin(require('@/Mixins/modules'))
    .mount(el)
```

**.mixin(require('@/Mixins/modules'))** in **app.js** file and in Mixins/modules this code

```
module.exports = {
methods: {
    _: () => _,
    route,
  },
};
```

some way uses Ziggy route

Answer (score 0):

Laravel11 + inertia finally works I changed position of .mount and add CreateApp as const:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
......
createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        const app = createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .use(i18nVue, {
                resolve: async lang => {
                    const langs = import.meta.glob('../../lang/*.json');
                    return await langs[`../../lang/${lang}.json`]();
                }
            });

        app.config.globalProperties.$_ = _;
        app.mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#4B5563',
    },
});
```

then we can use `$_.pull()` and other functions